# Wordpress post tiles out side of blog directory

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is it possible to pull tiles of blog posts into my php based website outside of the directory i'm hosting wordpress in? Im somewhat new to managing wordpress widgets so im not sure if one such widget or some code exists.

im aware i can include the wp-loader and i've been able to pull a quick list of recent posts but its querying my database which i don't know is too safe.

Is there a simpler way of accomplishing this without calling my database and make it easier to style?

```
<?php
include('/blog/wp-load.php');
?>

<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
'numberposts' => 10
));

echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], 
'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: You should accept & upvote my answer, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way to use WP RESTful API with curl for this purpose. You can get more details [see here](http://v2.wp-api.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get WordPress Post title out side the loop:

Change the `"blog"` to your project directory name

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php');
?>

<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
'numberposts' => 10
));

echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], 
'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```